# /boot full of kernels – what to delete?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

We have some Ubuntu 16.04 servers. `unattended-upgrades` are automatically enabled since 16.04 and `/boot` is a separate partition.
Due to the automatic security updates,
the boot partition is running out of space with new kernels.

We can't reboot the systems (for availability reasons),
so the machine is still using the penultimate kernel.

Which kernels should I remove? All but the current, the oldest and the newest?

Do you guys have some recommendations?

I have also noticed that the newest kernel has the status "Half Configured". This kernel would probably not work,
so should I remove this one and use an older kernel?

Output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`:

```
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic --> old kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic --> current kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic --> new kernel
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic --> new kernel
iF  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic --> new kernel
```

Answer (score 7):

To purge old kernel , you can use `purge-old-kernels` command line tool .

> This program will remove  old  kernel  and  header  packages  from  the
>          system, freeing disk space.  It will never remove the currently running
>          kernel.  By default, it will keep at least the latest  2  kernels,  but
>          the  user  can  override  that  value  using the --keep parameter.  Any
>          additional parameters will be passed directly to `apt-get`

To install [`purge-old-kernels`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/purge-old-kernels.1.html) , run:

```
sudo apt install byobu
```

or

```
sudo apt install bikeshed
```

To keep the latest `n` kernel run:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep n
```

e,g: n=2

```
sudo purge-old-kernels --keep 2
```

Update `grub`:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: `byobu` is probably the package you want for 16.04 Xenuial: `purge-old-kernels` got moved from `bikeshed` to `byobu` sometime between Trusty and Xenial, though `bikeshed` now recommends `byobu` so you'll still get the program unless you have no-install-recommends.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu, Grub2 automatically display the latest kernel and hides the older kernels. If you want to see them, you can press Shift while booting.

So, before deleting older kernels, boot with the latest available kernel (grub2 load it by default in booting). To check which kernel you are using you can use the command:

```
uname -r
```

The recommendation is to keep at least two or preferably three kernels including the latest. The reason is that you will have at least one/two other kernels to boot with if it occurs that you are unable to boot with the latest kernel.

To remove the older kernels, open terminal and check your current kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Then to list all installed kernels on your system.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Find all the kernels that lower than your current kernel. Run the commands below to remove the kernel you selected:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

Finally, run the commands below to update grub2

```
sudo update-grub2
```

And reboot your system.

Comment: From the question: _"we can't just reboot the systems"_. Your answer requires doing so twice.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get autoremove`, ran periodically, should be able to help you accomplish what you want. The running kernel, the previous kernel and the two latest kernels should be enough.

Comment: Given the list of installed kernels, and the fact that the running kernel is old, I'd say "the running kernel, the previous kernel and the two latest kernels".

Answer (score 3):

Boot one of the previous kernel.

First try `apt autoremove --purge`

If it not works  `dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'`

Control what will be deinstallt.

`dpkg -l 'linux-[ihs]*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\([-0-9]*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo dpkg -P`  This will purges the listet Kernel from command below.

```
sudo apt -f install
```

and for sure

```
 sudo update-grub
```